# Not able to load static file CSS and JS thru pyBottle?

Tags: python, bottle

Always getting 404 while trying to load static file using Bottle. I have referred stack overflow question and Google group chat but nothing is helping me to correct my problem. Please help me.. spent lot of time in this...

```
Tuts
   main.py
   static/
     bootstarp.css
   views/
     index.tpl
```

**main.py code**

```
import bottle
from bottle import Bottle
from os.path import basename,abspath, dirname, join

app = bottle.default_app()

appPath = dirname(abspath(''))
print appPath

@bottle.route('/')
def index():
    return bottle.template('index', dict(title=appPath,get_url=app.get_url))

@bottle.route('/static/:filename#.*#', name='css')
def server_static(filename):
    return bottle.static_file(filename, root=join(appPath,'static'))

bottle.debug(True)
bottle.run(host='localhost', port=8082,reloader=True)


**Template:**

<link href="{{ get_url('css', filename='bootstrap.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
from bottle import static_file
```

at top. Then just use `static_file(..., ...)` is fine:

```
@bottle.route('/static/:filename#.*#', name='css')
def server_static(filename):
    return static_file(filename, root=join(appPath,'static'))
```